# Unreal modular character tutorial errors

Tags: c++, unreal-4

I'm trying to follow the modular character tutorial for Unreal from this [link](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Animation/WorkingwithModularCharacters/index.html)
Specifically the mesh merge portion. How ever the code that is provided seems to not be working.

For example when I add this piece of code :

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct VR_API FSkelMeshMergeSectionMapping_BP
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Mesh Merge Params")
        TArray<type> SectionIDs;
};
```

I get the following error : `Unrecognized type 'type' - type must be a UCLASS, USTRUCT or UENUM`

I;m guessing I should provide a certain type in the <> but I have no idea what it should be. I've been using unreal only for 2 days now so if anyone can help me figure this tutorial out and get it working I would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TArray` is a template type in Unreal, which means you need to give it template parameters (within the angle brackets) when declaring one. In the case of `TArray`, you need *at a minimum* to indicate the type of data stored in the array. What you've written in your example is "a `TArray` of instances of `type`" and the error is telling you that there is no type named `type`.

"Section IDs" sound like they'd be integers, so you should probably write `TArray<int>` to create an array of `int`s. Or whichever other integer type is appropriate.

(Other than `TArray` itself, which is an Unreal type, this is a general C++ problem regarding [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates), so if you are looking for more background you don't need to look for Unreal-specific information... although the specific error you are seeing is an Unreal-specific one arising from how it parses your code and applies extra validation to `UPROPERTY` members, in this case putting additional constraints on the type parameter. `TArray` is roughly analogous in intent to the C++ standard library type `std::vector`.)

---

Reading through that tutorial link in more detail, much of the code samples seem to suffer from errors like this, including several declarations of `TArray` with no template parameters at all (which won't compile) as well as some stray characters at the end of some of the snippets.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you got this, but I worked it out pretty sure...

The goal is they're trying to make the existing ones in *SkeletalMeshMerge.h* editable on the blueprint side, so basically going into that file I could see what the arrays were.

So you want the **FSkelMeshMergeSectionMapping_BP** to contain *int32*'s:

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct MULTIPLAYERARENA_API FSkelMeshMergeSectionMapping_BP
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
        /** Indices to final section entries of the merged skeletal mesh */
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Mesh Merge Params")
        TArray<int32> SectionIDs;
};
```

and the **FSkelMeshMergeSectionMapping_BP** to contain *FTransform*'s:

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct MULTIPLAYERARENA_API FSkelMeshMergeUVTransform
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
        /** A list of how UVs should be transformed on a given mesh, where index represents a specific UV channel. */
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Mesh Merge Params")
        TArray<FTransform> UVTransforms;
};
```

and the **FSkelMeshMergeUVTransformMapping** to contain *FSkelMeshMergeUVTransform*'s:

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct MULTIPLAYERARENA_API FSkelMeshMergeUVTransformMapping
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
        /** For each UV channel on each mesh, how the UVS should be transformed. */
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Mesh Merge Params")
        TArray<FSkelMeshMergeUVTransform> UVTransformsPerMesh;
};
```

finally in the struct params themselves, like so:

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct MULTIPLAYERARENA_API FSkeletalMeshMergeParams
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
        FSkeletalMeshMergeParams()
    {
        MeshSectionMappings = TArray<FSkelMeshMergeSectionMapping_BP>();
        UVTransformsPerMesh = TArray<FSkelMeshMergeUVTransformMapping>();
        StripTopLODS = 0;
        bNeedsCpuAccess = false;
        bSkeletonBefore = false;
        Skeleton = nullptr;
    }
    // An optional array to map sections from the source meshes to merged section entries
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        TArray<FSkelMeshMergeSectionMapping_BP> MeshSectionMappings;
    // An optional array to transform the UVs in each mesh
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        TArray<FSkelMeshMergeUVTransformMapping> UVTransformsPerMesh;
    // The list of skeletal meshes to merge.
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        TArray<class USkeletalMesh*> MeshesToMerge;
    // The number of high LODs to remove from input meshes
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        int32 StripTopLODS;
    // Whether or not the resulting mesh needs to be accessed by the CPU for any reason (e.g. for spawning particle effects).
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        uint32 bNeedsCpuAccess : 1;
    // Update skeleton before merge. Otherwise, update after.
    // Skeleton must also be provided.
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        uint32 bSkeletonBefore : 1;
    // Skeleton that will be used for the merged mesh.
    // Leave empty if the generated skeleton is OK.
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly)
        class USkeleton* Skeleton;
};
```

It compiles and it works with meshes, but I haven't used these optional parameters so don't know if they actually work

Answer (score 1):

To add to Alex Coultas's solution, the final UProperty in the **FSkeletalMeshMergeParams** struct has to be *BlueprintReadWrite* like the others, otherwise you get yellow warnings in the output box.

```
// Skeleton that will be used for the merged mesh.
// Leave empty if the generated skeleton is OK.
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
    class USkeleton* Skeleton;
```